# Convert big number to hex in tcl

Tags: tcl

Converting `0x100200300` to hex? I've written it in hex but it is being held as decimal in a variable called `value`.

```
set temp 0x[format %x $value]
```

Cuts the leading 1. What format should I use? as the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/format.htm#M5) doesn't give a format...

Comment: It works fine for me with Tcl 8.6.8. But in an older Tcl version you may have to use `format %lx $value`

Comment: You must be running on a 32-bit platform?

Comment: He's pointing to the Tcl 8.4 documentation. In 8.4 I see what he reports, on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: Google likes to point to the 8.4 documentation. We should fix that sometime…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To format a hex value of arbitrary width, use the `ll` modifier. Assuming you're using Tcl 8.5 or later.

```
format 0x%llx 123123123123123123123123123123123
# ==> 0x61208446788844c1533f84ff3b3
```

(If you're using 8.4 still, that won't work. And 8.4 is unsupported.)

Comment: The `l` modifier _might_ work for you, but `ll` definitely does he trick.