# Converting character to hex via Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to convert some characters into hex using tcl.

And i would usually do something like this: `[binary format a* 'o']` that return 111, which is the int representation of 'o' that can then be converted.

However the way that i retrive the character, `[value string_split]` returns "o" instead of 'o' cuasing the the function to throw an error, esentially like doing: `[binary format a* "o"]` which returns "ERROR: Nothing is named "o""

So, what is the difference between "o" and 'o' in a tcl context and how can i get my `[binary format a* [value string_split]]` call to return 111 like `[binary format a* 'o']` would do.

It should be noted that i am using TheFoundry's Nuke to do this and I don't know exactly what version of TCL they are using, but it is a rather old one.

Comment: Did you search for prior Q&A before submitting your Q? E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992318/convert-big-number-to-hex-in-tcl

Comment: Yes, extensively. This question was specifically about turning a char into hex, not a big number like the one you link to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scan`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/scan.html) with a format of `%c` to get the Unicode codepoint value of a character, and then [`format`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.html) to print it as hex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set o_str o
scan $o_str %c o_value
puts $o_value ;# 111
puts [format 0x%x $o_value] ;# 0x6f
```

Comment: `format %#x $o_value` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case of a string, including a string of length 1, since Tcl 8.6 one can also do:

```
binary encode hex $input_string
binary decode hex $hex_string
```

This assumes that `$input_string` is already “binary”, so for text it would be wise to first:

```
set input_string [encoding convertto utf-8 $input_string]
```

Comment: Only works for characters in the unsigned byte range.